# How does file truncate works in python?

Tags: python, truncate, truncation

I have a simple question about truncating files in python. Let's say that I have a file called myfile.txt and I have inside the phrase *hello what are you doing* in one line.

First of all I open the file:
`f = open('c:/Users/User/Desktop/myfile.txt','r')`

Then if I use `f.truncate(5)` and close the file it will change the file and inside it, will be *hello*.
That means give me 5 bytes of the file no matter the position of the cursor (correct me if I am wrong). If I don't use any number in the truncate method ,it is going to delete everything inside the file. However if I read the file `f.read(6)` that means that the cursor is now at the position 6 (I can see that using `f.tell()`) and then I use `f.truncate()` then nothing happens to the file and nothing is changed. Why is that? I moved the cursor to positon 6 and then I use truncate... On [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_truncate.asp), they say that if I don't put anything inside `truncate` then *the current position will be used*. What does that mean?

Comment: What did you expect to happen instead? And what did *you* mean by "position" when you use it a few lines earlier?

Comment: i am a little bit confused about the truncate and i didn't understand it when i read it's definition. Could you explain it to me in simple words?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem, just now. Just open your file in `'r+b'` mode.

For some reason I am still a bit unsure about, opening the file in binary mode caused `truncate` to work as described in the docs. Also don't forget to add the `+` mode too. It won't work for files open just for reading.

This isn't a singular case either. There are quite a few more file object methods that work as intended on files open in binary mode and less so on files open in the default text mode.

Anyway, hope that helps.